# Add block to each product in category view

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, blocks

I'm trying to add a small form to the category view to each product by using the `<catalog_category_view>` layout handle. The block of my module already works on product detail pages (`<catalog_product_view>` in `product.info` block).

Is there some requirement for the `product_list` block to accept another child block which I'm calling explicitly by name within the `catalog/product/list.phtml`? My form block class extends the basic `Mage_Core_Block_Template` if it makes any difference.

edit: *added source*

```
<!-- working -->
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="annotations/form" template="productannotations/form.phtml" name="product_annotations" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

<!-- not working -->
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <block type="annotations/form" template="productannotations/form.phtml" name="product_annotations" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

embeding the block directly via
`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('annotations/form', 'product_annotations')->setTemplate('productannotations/form.phtml')->toHtml()` works on the other hand.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: @Marius added my layout.xml code. Also I changed the extending class from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` to `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`

Answer (score 1):

you can add new block like below.

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
      <block type="core/template" name="product_custom_form" template="path/to/phtml"/>
</block>
```

In Listing file add code  in foreach of product collection like below:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<form name="producid-form" action="yoururl">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_custom_form'); ?>
</form>
```

Note: add only input fields in you form phtml