# Add a button to each Product in category view by own module

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, template

I am very new to Magento and have to add a Button to each product in product category view and all other product lists (not detail product view).

I nearly found an answer in [Add block to each product in category view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61217/add-block-to-each-product-in-category-view), but I don't want to override any original files. So that solution seems not working for me.

I tried to extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List, but I do not really find an appropriate function to use.

Please, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use _afterToHtml method

```
class Company_Module_Block_Model extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _afterToHtml($html)
    {
        return $html . '<div>Some text is here</div>';
    }
}
```

Or parse your $html as you like

Comment: Thanks! Extending Mage_Core_Block_Template this way gives me an error: `Invalid method Webshopxcalibur_Block_Model::addColumnCountLayoutDepend(Array(
    [0] => empty
    [1] => 6
)
)`
I tried also to extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List by overriding _afterToHtml($html). It gave me the correct output, but only once at the end of the whole list. I want my output at each product of the list. Do you have any idea?